# Ajax Request Failing on Android Phone App

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, cordova

I am developing mobile browser based app (HTML5 + JQuery Mobile + PhoneGap). When I install the app and login, login works good. When I register user, I am redirected back to Login page, and then I try logging in, it fails with a Bad Request error. After random time 2 hours or may be 4 hours. When I try to login with the same user, system will let me login without any issue until I create a new dummy user again and come back to login page. Login will start failing again. I've already turned off the cache (cache:false) in ajax call.

Same scenario always work perfect on any browser in workstation. Only smartphone creates issue.

Here is my code:

```
function CheckLogin() {

var vaildate = ValidateForm();
if (vaildate != false) {
    "use strict";
    var wcfServiceUrl = "http://www.myService.com/myService/myService.svc/XMLService/";

    var name = $('#txtUserName');
    var password = $('#txtPassword');
    var fileData = base64_encode(name.val() + ":" + password.val()); // this is encoding and works fine.
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: wcfServiceUrl + "Login",
        type: "GET",
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        timeout: 90000,
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,

        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", base64_encode(name.val() + ":" + password.val()));
        },
        complete: function () {
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        },

        success: function (data) {

                window.localStorage.setItem("userid", data.LoginUserResult);
                window.localStorage.setItem("loginname", name.val());
                $.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
                window.location.href = 'web/Default.html';
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
              alert(xhr.responseText + ' ---STATUS--- ' + xhr.status);

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Just for testing purposes..try removing `"use strict";`.

Comment: @Kamran On ajax call failure, whats the error code and status?

Comment: @Hackerman Removing "use strict" is not helping, just tried.

Comment: @Gandhi Status is 400, error message says "Server encounterd and error processesing request. Please see the <a>service help</a> for constructing valid request...". Interestingly as I said above, this will start working fine automatically after some random time.

Comment: @Kamran During failure, whats the final URL that gets formed before invoking the server?

Comment: @Gandhi, Thank you for your continued interest in this issue. Below is the final URI: 
http://www.myService.com/myService/myService.svc/XMLService/Login

Comment: @Kamran This can never give out an invalid request error. There should be something more to this. Try making a simple call without any headers and data and see if it works first

Comment: I am suspecting it has something to do with local cache or something is blocking the way to the service which is released after some random time. Login starts working an hour or a couple of hours later.